# Can these awk actions be combined/optimised, or done differently?

Tags: optimization, awk

I have three bits of awk strung together which seems to do what I need, but could it be done more efficiently/completely differently?

Currently, the three stages are:

1. Quick & dirty check whether field 2 contains an IP or FQDN
2. Reverse the last (up to) three elements of the FQDN
3. Aggregate the number of occurrences of the field pairing

```
awk '$2~/[a-z,A-Z,0-9]\.[a-z,A-Z]+$/{print$2,$1,$3}' ???.20201001.txt|awk '{n=split($1,a,".");for(i=0;i<3&&i<n;i++)printf ".%s",a[n-i];print"",$2,$3}'|[$1 " " $2] +=$3} END {for(i in combo) print i, combo[i]}'> combos.20201001.txt
```

In the log being parsed the fields are:

1. IP address
2. FQDN
3. Count

"

```
An input file consisting of: 
1.2.3.5 four.three.two.com 14
1.2.3.5 four.three.two.com 34
1.2.3.5 different.biz 12
7.8.9.1 four.three.two.com 5


should output:
.biz.different 1.2.3.5 12
.com.two.three 1.2.3.5 48
.com.two.three 7.8.9.1 5
```

"

The order of the lines output is not important (a job for sort) and the only reason the abbreviated FQDN has been moved from the middle to the front of the line is that is the only way I could get my awk to output the three fields on the same line.

"

```
1.2.3.5 .biz.different 12
1.2.3.5 .one.two.three 48
7.8.9.1 .one.two.three 5
```

"

Would be acceptable, even preferable.
Apologies for the formatting; it's somewhat of challenge.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts in your question, please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question for better understanding, thank you.

Comment: You don't need to pipe the output of awk into awk again. You should be able to process the file in one go.

Comment: `[a-z,A-Z]` means "the upper or lower case letters a through z or a comma". If you instead intended to match "the upper or lower case letters a through z" that'd be just `[a-zA-Z]` or more portably `[[:alpha:]]`. When you say "Reverse the **first** (up to) three elements" - you really mean "Reverse the **last** (up to) three elements" right? Or is the expected output incorrect?

Comment: @Ed, you're right, I meant the last three elements of the FQDN, and the comma should not be there (but I've left it; making changes is muddling things up). Your answer looks good; I'll have a proper chew at it tomorrow and see if I can understand it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 ~ /[[:alnum:]]\.[[:alpha:]]+$/ {
    end = split($2,parts,/[.]/)
    beg = end - 2
    beg = (beg>0 ? beg : 1)
    for (i=beg; i<=end; i++) {
        fqdn = parts[i] (i == beg ? "" : "." fqdn)
    }
    key = $1 OFS fqdn
    count[key] += $3
}
END {
    for (key in count) {
        print key, count[key]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
7.8.9.1 one.two.three 5
1.2.3.5 one.different 12
1.2.3.5 one.two.three 48
```